# Intent.type = "image/* does not make any effect on Huawei

Tags: android-intent, huawei-developers

I want to get a bunch of photos from an other app. I want the content to be pictures only, so I'm trying to pick pictures with this code:

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*"))
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_PICTURES)
```

And it works the way it should on every device possible except Huawei where I'm able to pick any type of file.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something special about Huawei devices regarding this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet for Huawei devices.

```
val getPhoto = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif")
getPhoto.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
getPhoto.type = "image/*"
startActivityForResult(getPhoto,REQUEST_CODE_PICK_PICTURES)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. I think the problem is in huawei file manager app. But thanks anyway